# Serializar datos de objetos compiladas en una libreria de clases

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Saludos, tengo un problema con un ejercicio de serializacion. El tema es el siguiente:
Tengo una ClassLibrary con las clases Fruta (abstracta), Manzana y Platano que derivan de Fruta y otra clase Cajon que contiene una lista de "frutas", el programa me funciona correctamente salvo por un error al momento de serializar:

```
public bool SerializarXML()
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            Type[] extras = new Type[2];
            extras[0] = typeof(Manzana);
            extras[1] = typeof(Platano);
            using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Cajon.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cajon), extras);
                xs.Serialize(xtw, this);
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); ;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Todas las clases estan como públicas, y contiene los marcadores:

```
 [Serializable]
```

en la clase fruta ademas contiene:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Manzana))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Platano))]
```

Pero me lanza un error que dice: `Error al reflejar el tipo SP2015.Manzana`, donde SP2015 es el nombre del namespace. Aclaro además que el Main se encuentra en OTRO proyecto, de tipo Consola donde intento llamar al metodo SerializarXML().
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3):

Pero no estas serializando datos, sino que envias el objeto `Type` a la serializacion

```
public bool SerializarXML(List<Fruta> datos)
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Cajon.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruta));
            xs.Serialize(xtw, datos);
            success = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return success;
}
```

como observaras envias una List<> de Fruta para serializar, pero son datos usandolo de esta forma

```
List<Fruta> list = new List<Fruta>();
list.Add(new Manzana());
list.Add(new Platano());

SerializarXML(list);
```

Comment: Al parecer SerializarXML es un método de `Cajon`, entonces `this` se refiera a la instancia de `Cajon`, que probablemente tiene una propiedad `Frutas` de tipo `List<Fruta>`.